# Postman raw data works but form-data not works on POST request in php

Tags: php, jwt

I'm creating reset login signup api in PHP using JWT and I'm facing some problems when using postman. When I'll try to send raw data in JSON(application/json) format, it gets success but when I send form-data, it's not working.

**login api**

```
<?PHP
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

 function msg($success,$status,$message,$extra = []){
 return array_merge([
    'success' => $success,
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $message
],$extra);
}

// INCLUDING DATABASE AND MAKING OBJECT
require __DIR__.'/classes/Database.php';
$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();

// GET DATA FORM REQUEST
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$returnData = [];

// IF REQUEST METHOD IS NOT POST
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"):
$returnData = msg(0,404,'Page Not Found!');

// CHECKING EMPTY FIELDS
elseif(!isset($data->firstname)
|| !isset($data->lastname)
|| !isset($data->mobile)
|| !isset($data->email) 
|| !isset($data->password)
|| !isset($data->class)
|| empty(trim($data->firstname))
|| empty(trim($data->lastname))
|| empty(trim($data->mobile))
|| empty(trim($data->email))
|| empty(trim($data->password))
|| empty(trim($data->class))
):

$fields = ['fields' => ['firstname', 'lastname', 'mobile', 'email', 'password', 'class']];
$returnData = msg(0,422,'Please Fill in all Required Fields!',$fields);

// IF THERE ARE NO EMPTY FIELDS THEN-
else:

$firstname = trim($data->firstname);
$lastname = trim($data->lastname);
$mobile = trim($data->mobile);
$email = trim($data->email);
$password = trim($data->password);
$class = trim($data->class);


if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'Invalid Email Address!');

elseif(strlen($password) < 8):
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'Your password must be at least 8 characters long!');

elseif(strlen($firstname) < 3):
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'Your first name must be at least 3 characters long!');

elseif(strlen($lastname) < 3):
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'Your last name must be at least 3 characters long!');

elseif(strlen($mobile) < 10):
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'Your mobile number must be at least 10 characters long!');    

else:
    try{

        $check_email = "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email";
        $check_email_stmt = $conn->prepare($check_email);
        $check_email_stmt->bindValue(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check_email_stmt->execute();

        if($check_email_stmt->rowCount()):
            $returnData = msg(0,422, 'This E-mail already in use!');

        else:
            $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`firstname`,`lastname`,`mobile`,`email`,`password`,`class`) VALUES(:firstname,:lastname,:mobile,:email,:password,:class)";

            $insert_stmt = $conn->prepare($insert_query);

            // DATA BINDING
            $insert_stmt->bindValue(':firstname', 
            htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($firstname)),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_stmt->bindValue(':lastname', 
            htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($lastname)),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_stmt->bindValue(':mobile', $mobile,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_stmt->bindValue(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_stmt->bindValue(':password', password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insert_stmt->bindValue(':class', $class,PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $insert_stmt->execute();

            $returnData = msg(1,201,'You have successfully registered.');

        endif;

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $returnData = msg(0,500,$e->getMessage());
    }
endif;

endif;

echo json_encode($returnData);
```

please tell me where I'm wrong and help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

[image: sending data using form-data]
[image: sending data using raw]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't correct sending the form to the your API endpoint.

Step 1. - Use the header params! (Header tab - key:value -> Content-type: application/json)

Step 2. - Don't use formdata options! This method send simple POST request without json_encoding! You can only use raw option.

Comment: @Lasziooo thanks for your answer but the android developer wants API in only formdata, tell me what I do??????

Comment: If only the form can be submitted, use middleware solution. Able to receive post request and convert to json format IF the request header not include json/application content type. BUT the android developer should be able to generate json file.

Comment: @AyushSrivastava What approach you applied to solve your issue? Have you resolved your problem? If yes, then post your answer here so others can be benefited.

Comment: @MuhammadTariq sir I change the method

Comment: @AyushSrivastava Can you please briefly share your method, if possible.